# Matrix diagram in r

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create such a diagram in r:

[image]

I have a such matrix

```
 [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5] .... [30]

[1] 0.5   0.75  1.5   0.25  2.5 .... 0.51

[1] 0.84  0.24  3.5   0.85  0.25.... 1.75

[1] 0.35  4.2   0.52  1.5   0.35.... 0.75
.
. .......................................
.
[30]0.84  1.24  0.55   1.5  0.85.... 2.75
```

and I want to have a diagram,

- if the value less than one ----> green circle
- if the value between one and two ----> yellow circle
- more than two ----> red circle

Is there any packages or method in r to do this job? how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to plot this, you need three data points:

```
x, y, color
```

Thus, first step is reshaping.
Fortunately, matricies are already a vector, simply with a dimension attribute, so we just need to create a data.frame of x,y coordinates.  We do this with `expand.grid`.

```
# create sample data. 
mat <- matrix(round(runif(900-30, 0, 5),2), 30)
```

create the (x, y) data.frame.
Notice that `y` is the seq of *rows* and `x` the seq of *columns*

```
dat <- expand.grid(y=seq(nrow(mat)), x=seq(ncol(mat)))

## add in the values from the matrix. 
dat <- data.frame(dat, value=as.vector(mat))

## Create a column with the appropriate colors based on the value.
dat$color <- cut( dat$value, 
                  breaks=c(-Inf, 1, 2, Inf), 
                  labels=c("green", "yellow", "red")
                 )



## Plotting
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(color=dat$color, size=7)
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: thank you for your nice answer, could you please say me what makes `breaks=c(-Inf, 1, 2, Inf)` ?

Comment: @kaja, no prob.   the `cut` statement is just a simpler way of making three separate `ifelse()` statements.  It segments a continuous vector and every value within the breaks is a group.  the `labels` argument indicates what to label each group as

Answer (score 3):

If your data is a result of correlation, then [corrplot package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) can be useful.

> The corrplot package is a graphical display of a correlation matrix,
>   confidence interval. It also contains some algorithms to do matrix
>   reordering. In addition, corrplot is good at details, including
>   choosing color, text labels, color labels, layout, etc.

Example plot based on @RicardoSaporta sample data.

```
library(corrplot)

#sample data
mat <- matrix(round(runif(900, 0, 5),2), 30)

#plot
corrplot(mat, is.corr = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you could have used simply the base function `image`:

```
mat <- matrix(round(runif(900-30, 0, 5),2), 30)
image(mat,
      breaks=c(min(mat),1,2,max(mat)), #image can't handle Inf but that's not a problem here
      col=c("green","yellow","red"), axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Or if you prefer dots instead of cells:

```
grid <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mat),1:ncol(mat)) #Same two steps as in Ricardo Sapporta answer
category <- cut(mat,c(-Inf,1,2,Inf))
plot(grid,                  #Then plot using base plot
     col=c("green","yellow","red")[category], #here is the trick
     pch=19, cex=2, axes=FALSE) #You can customize it as you wish
```

[image]